модули stdin и stdout в node.js работают не корректно
Всем привет. У меня возникли трудности с работой node.js. В частности с модулями ввода и вывод. Я подключил модули
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs/promises");
const readFile = require("readline");

Далее я читаю файлы .txt с помощью fs
const cat = fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "../EQ/cat.txt"), "utf-8");
const shark = fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "../EQ/shark.txt"), "utf-8");
const snake = fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "../EQ/snake.txt"), "utf-8");


Далее я создаю функции которые возвращают мне значения  моделей
function ModelCat() {
  cat.then((data) => console.log(data.split("\n")));
}
function ModelShark() {
  shark.then((data) => console.log(data.split("\n")));
}
function ModelSnake() {
  snake.then((data) => console.log(data.split("\n")));
}

Далее создаю функцию которая в зависимости от ввода пользователя определенного индекса возвращает мне нужную модель
function getModelINDEX(item) {
  if (item === 0) {
    return ModelCat();
  } else if (item === 1) {
    return ModelShark();
  } else if (item === 2) {
    return ModelSnake();
  }
}

И тут возникает проблема. По документации я вроде все написал правильно.
const rl = readFile.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});
rl.on("data", (data) => getModelINDEX(data));

Когда я ввожу определенную цифру он мне ничего не возвращает. Что не так. Может я что то упустил?

Все твои функции типа Mode* вернут undefined...

Почему вернут undefined? Когда я вызываю функцию c индексом он работает корректно

Попробуйте так getModelINDEX(+data) или getModelINDEX(Number(data))

rl.on("data", (data) => getModelINDEX(data)); в переменной data будет строка, а в вашей проверке строгое соотвествие номеру if (item === 0). замените на нестрогое соотвествие, ==

Почему вернут undefined? у этих функций нет явного return <значение> - значит будет "не явный" return undefined...

Не работает. Я тоже думал, что дело в  type

Еще, как вариант - чтение файлов завершается быстрее, чем вы успеваетет ввести что то в консоль и все промисы к этому моменту уже разрешены. Добавьте в каждую функцию консоль.лог и смотрете, что где у вас происходит после ввода данных в консоль.
